# to know the character in a object-c nsstring object

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an NSString *str and I want to know if the 2nd character is equal to a. How can I do this? I'm new to objective c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
[str characterAtIndex:1]
```

But I always encourage you to check documentation first!

Comment: and how do I see if it equals to 'a'?

Comment: Check the documentation to see what -characterAtIndex return and compare. try [str characterAtIndex:1] == (unichar)'a'.

Comment: From the documentation: `- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
[[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,1)] isEqualToString:@"a"];
```

Admittedly, this only becomes handy when you have longer strings for which you're searching.